# How to Set the Processor Affinity for .NET WCF Web Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a question about relegating a 3rd party process hosted in a WCF service to a single core. I am utilizing a third party tool as part of my WCF web service that bases licensing costs per processor core.

It is my understanding that setting processor affinity can be done by setting up an `IIS App Pool Resource Allocation Policy` via the Windows System Resource Manager on Windows Server 2008. After the policy has been created, you can then assign the WCF service to that IIS app pool restricted by the policy thus making it so that service is only using the designated core allotted.

If I assign my web service to an app pool that is configured to run under the restricted processor affinity policy, can I be assured that all third party tools utilized by the service will also be restricted to the processor(s) allowed by the policy (assuming the tool does not spin up its own process)?